# Waiting for rendering a chart till data has loaded

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, asynchronous, d3.js

I have made a small chart using D3.js.

1. There are 3 different kind of load functions for different kinds of input data types.
2. My chart can be rendered on any of these datasets, one at a time based on the parameter passed to the render function.
3. The data loading code is async which creates a problem because my render function starts drawing even before data has fully loaded.
4. I have given separate load functions instead of calling them inside render function because user might want to just load the data sets initially and render the chart later.
5. I thought of waiting on a flag before starting drawing and set this flag when all the data sets have uploaded, but looks ugly to me coz of an infinite loop.

Any ideas in term of design I could use to make this work ?

```
    var visualization = new  Chart()
                          .width(1000)
                          .height(1000)
                          .loadDissimilarityMatrix('dataSet1.csv')
                          .loadAdjacencyMatrix('dataSet2.csv')
                          .loadLaplacianMatrix('dataSet3.csv')
                          .render('Dissimilarity')
                          // .render('Adjacency') for using the adjacency dataset.
```

Comment: Yes, you can't do that, you need to put the d3 code on your csv call-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

I realize that the data loading part should be left with the API user. Instead of asking for a URL to load the files, I should just ask for the direct data. Responsibility of showing the 'busy screen' etc. should all lie with the API user.

He should call the chart creation and rendering code on his callback when data sets have fully loaded. My chart can them directly render without being concerned of data being still loaded.

I checked some APIs and I found none which held responsibility of parsing and loading the data as well.

P.S. Open for suggestions.